# IOS Compass Reading comes out different in different controllers

Tags: ios, compass-geolocation

I have a problem with compass reading. I have two different controllers and in both the controllers the compass reading turns out different in the same location and same direction. How to fix that?

```
self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.headingFilter = 0.1;
self.locationManager.delegate=self;
```

This is how I initializing the location manager in both the controllers.

Comment: Do you have any idea about that i need any solution urgent. I have tried many things but of no use. And also the difference is not the same in all the cases. Sometimes the difference is as slight as 1.2 and sometimes as big as 31 to 35